# In Liquibase what is the reasonable limitation for the number of migrations / changesets

Tags: database-migration, liquibase, changeset, changelog

In my understanding, every `liquibase update` run

- goes through the complete *changelog* file
- for every *changeset* met it calculates it's MD5 sum value
- and for every *changeset* checks it against DATABASECHANGELOG table to see whether *changeset* already deployed or modified

If imagine the large number of changesets already deployed, for example, tens of thousands or more, the process of adding just a single changeset might seem (at least theoretically) time consuming.

What is the correlation between the number of changesets and "migration" time? Are there any limitations? If yes, what are the possible alternative solutions for database migrations with big amount of objects and changes?